# Can jquery's UI slider be used witha delegate selector?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider

I'm using jquery slider, which is called from either `document.ready()` or `ajax pageLoad()` function

```
$(".slider").slider({
        slide: function (event, ui) {

            // do something
        },
        create: function (event, ui) {

            // do something else
        }
    });
```

Because I use Asp.Net AJAX (update panels), the best way of integrating jQuery functions is to do it through delegation using the `.on` function.

Typically, I would use a line like this in document.ready and forget about it.

```
    $('body').on('click', 'input.validates', setInputStateOnSubmit);
```

Is there any way of using the slider call in this way?

Answer (score 1):

You can use event delegation for registering event handlers

```
$(document).on('slidecreate', '.slider', function (event, ui) {
    // do something
}).on('slide', '.slider', function (event, ui) {
    // do something else
});
```

- [slide event](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-slide)
- [create event](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-create)

But still you will have to initialize the widget after the element is added to the dom like

```
$('.slider').slider()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ysg3U/)