# How do I delegate a jQuery UI slider to the DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-slider

I have this *range* slider using the jQuery UI API, and it worked as expected but now i'm trying to delegate the slider to the DOM and no matter what I try it doesn't work. Here is my initial code (no selector delegation):

## HTML [initial]

```
<div class="SliderContainer">
                    
    <input type="hidden" id="minWT" value="2.5" />
    <input type="hidden" id="maxWT" value="30" />

    <p class="wtNumber" id="showWT">2.5Ct - 30Ct</p>

    <div class="rangeContainer">
        <div id="WTrange"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

## JS [initial]

```
$('#WTrange').slider({
        
    range: true,
    values: [2.50, 30.00],
    min: 2.50,
    max: 30.00,
    step: 0.01,
    change:

        function(event, ui) {
            
            alert('Things have changed!');
            
        },
    slide: 

        function(event, ui) {
            
            // Prevent range thumbs from overlapping
            if ((ui.values - ui.values[1]) < 3) {

                return false;

            }
        
            $('#showWT').html(ui.values[0] + 'Ct - ' + ui.values[1] + 'Ct'); // Show value above range slider
            $('#minWT').val(ui.values[0]);
            $('#maxWT').val(ui.values[1]);
            
        }
        
});
```

After doing some Googling I found [this potential solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22450362/can-jquerys-ui-slider-be-used-witha-delegate-selector/22450410#22450410). But i'm either doing something wrong or it doesn't work because I can't seem to get it right:

## Failed JS Attempt 1

```
$('#WTrange').slider();

$(document).on('slidecreate', '#WTrange', function(event, ui) {

}).on('slider', '#WTrange', function(event, ui) {

    range: true,
    values: [2.50, 30.00],
    min: 2.50,
    max: 30.00,
    step: 0.01
        
}).on('slidechange', '#WTrange', function(event, ui) {

    alert('Things have changed!');
  
}).on('slide', '#WTrange', function(event, ui) {

  // Prevent range thumbs from overlapping
  if ((ui.values - ui.values[1]) < 3) {

      return false;

  }

    $('#showWT').html(ui.values[0] + 'Ct - ' + ui.values[1] + 'Ct'); // Show value above range slider
    $('#minWT').val(ui.values[0]);
    $('#maxWT').val(ui.values[1]);

});
```

When [running this (in JSFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/t1kaorqd/) I get this error:

```
"<a class='gotoLine' href='#35:9'>35:9</a> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'"
```

- [The jQuery UI Slider Widget API manual that I've been referencing to
  do this](https://api.jqueryui.com/slider/)

---

Does anyone know the correct way of delegating this jQuery UI slider widget to the DOM?

---

#### EDIT 1

I tried reformatting it to delegate and it still didn't work:

## Failed JS Attempt 2

```
$('#WTrange').slider();
$(document).on('slide', '#WTrange', 'option', 'range', true);
$(document).on('slide', '#WTrange', 'option', 'values' [2.50, 30.00]);
$(document).on('slide', '#WTrange', 'option', 'min', 2.50);
$(document).on('slide', '#WTrange', 'option', 'max', 30.00);
$(document).on('slide', '#WTrange', 'option', 'step', 0.01);
$(document).on('slidechange', '#WTrange', function(event, ui) {

    alert('Things have changed!');

});

$(document).on('slide', '#WTrange', function(event, ui) {

    // Prevent range thumbs from overlapping
    if ((ui.values - ui.values[1]) < 3) {
    
        return false;
    
    }
    
    $('#showWT').html(ui.values[0] + 'Ct - ' + ui.values[1] + 'Ct'); // Show value above range slider
    $('#minWT').val(ui.values[0]);
    $('#maxWT').val(ui.values[1]);

});
```

#### EDIT 2

I was told that my question wasn't clear enough. Here is a [more minimal and reproducible example](https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

## HTML on `$(document).ready()`

```
<div id="pageContent">
    <button>Show Slider</button>
</div>
```

**NOTICE:** No HTML for the jQuery UI slider

## JS on `$(document).ready()`

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
    $('#pageContent').load('sliderPage.php');
});

$('#WTrange').slider({

    range: true,
    values: [2.50, 30.00],
    min: 2.50,
    max: 30.00,
    step: 0.01,
    change:

        function(event, ui) {

            alert('Things have changed!');

        },
    slide: 

        function(event, ui) {

            // Prevent range thumbs from overlapping
            if ((ui.values - ui.values[1]) < 3) {

                return false;

            }

            $('#showWT').html(ui.values[0] + 'Ct - ' + ui.values[1] + 'Ct'); // Show value above range slider
            $('#minWT').val(ui.values[0]);
            $('#maxWT').val(ui.values[1]);

        }

});
```

**NOTICE:** When the user `.click()`s the `<button>` sliderPage.php will `.load()`

## HTML after sliderPage.php *loaded* on `<button>` click

```
<div id="pageContent">
    <div class="SliderContainer">

        <input type="hidden" id="minWT" value="2.5" />
        <input type="hidden" id="maxWT" value="30" />
    
        <p class="wtNumber" id="showWT">2.5Ct - 30Ct</p>
    
        <div class="rangeContainer">
            <div id="WTrange"></div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

**NOTICE:** Now there is HTML for the jQuery UI slider on the same page

---

**ESSENTIAL QUESTION:**
Because the HTML contents of `<div class="SliderContainer">` weren't part of the DOM on `$(document).ready()` their events have to be `.delegate()`d up the DOM tree. How can I delegate this jQuery UI slider so my JS recognizes it?

Comment: `slider` is a plugin, not an event.  You most likely cannot delegate it.

Comment: Would you know if there's any other way to show it after `.load()`ing the parent selector besides for delegating it then?

Comment: You would initialize it at the point in time that it is needed/available.

Comment: Sorry i'm kind of new to this; what do you mean by _initialize_?

Comment: `$('#WTrange').slider({` <== this call to `slider()` is "initializing" the plugin logic.  It's the setup step.

Comment: The `:` error is coming up cause you are defining object elements inside a Function call. Example: `.on('slider', '#WTrange', function(event, ui) { range: true,`

Comment: Where should I define the object elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please review: https://api.jqueryui.com/slider/

Here is an example of how to use this.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#WTrange').slider({
    range: true,
    values: [2.50, 30.00],
    min: 2.50,
    max: 30.00,
    step: 0.01
  }).on("slidechange", function(event, ui) {
    alert('Things have changed!');
  }).on("slide", function(event, ui) {
    if ((ui.values - ui.values[1]) < 3) {
      return false;
    }
    $('#showWT').html(ui.values[0] + 'Ct - ' + ui.values[1] + 'Ct');
    $('#minWT').val(ui.values[0]);
    $('#maxWT').val(ui.values[1]);
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="SliderContainer">
  <input type="hidden" id="minWT" value="2.5" />
  <input type="hidden" id="maxWT" value="30" />
  <p class="wtNumber" id="showWT">2.5Ct - 30Ct</p>
  <div class="rangeContainer">
    <div id="WTrange"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update**

As you stated in your edit, you are using `.load()` to pull in the needed HTML and then initialize it with jQuery UI Slider. I would use the complete callback feature of `.load()`. See More: https://api.jquery.com/load/

> Type: Function( String responseText, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR ) A callback function that is executed when the request completes.

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('#pageContent').load('sliderPage.php', function(){
    $('#WTrange').slider({
      range: true,
      values: [2.50, 30.00],
      min: 2.50,
      max: 30.00,
      step: 0.01,
      slide: function(event, ui) {
        if ((ui.values - ui.values[1]) < 3) {
          return false;
        }
        $('#showWT').html(ui.values[0] + 'Ct - ' + ui.values[1] + 'Ct');
        $('#minWT').val(ui.values[0]);
        $('#maxWT').val(ui.values[1]);
      },
      change: function(event, ui) {
        alert('Things have changed!');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Now the elements will exist and the events will bind successful. You won't need delegation. The crux of the issue would be that you cannot delegate the initialization of `.slider()`. You can delegate `change` and `slide` events, but not the initial `.slider()` call, since it's not an event.

**Update 2**

As your content cannot be tested by others, I created a pseudo test in JSFiddnle: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/zjeLdmw5/8/

This echos the HTML back to the `.load()` function in the same sort of way your pages load the content. When I click the button, the content is replaced with the HTML and then Slider is initialized.

This shows the code I suggested works. There may be some other issue with your code that is not yet clear.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219150/discussion-on-answer-by-twisty-how-do-i-delegate-a-jquery-ui-slider-to-the-dom).